Getting error for django and react native code Forbidden (CSRF token missing.):
I am working on a Django backend to handle some data manipulation, specifically appending and deleting data. My code works perfectly when tested with Postman, but I encounter a 403 Forbidden error when trying to access the /bookings/remove/ endpoint from my React Native frontend.
Here's the error message I receive:
Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /bookings/remove/ "POST /bookings/remove/?booking_id=148/ HTTP/1.1" 403
Interestingly, all other endpoints are working fine without any CSRF-related issues. It's only this specific endpoint that is causing problems.
Django Backend
i have my settings for cors as follows:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    "all other apps"
]

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}

and my endpoint for which i am getting error is
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@csrf_exempt
def cancel_the_booking(request, booking_id):
    try:
        if not booking_id:
            return Response({"error": "Booking ID is required"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        booking = Booking.objects.get(booking_id=booking_id)
        if booking.host_id != request.user.id:
            return Response({"error": "You are not authorized to cancel this booking", "host": request.user.id}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        for date_price in booking.dates_price.all():
            AdSpaceDates.objects.create(
                ad_space=booking.space_id,
                available_from=date_price.available_from,
                available_to=date_price.available_to,
                price=date_price.price
            )

        booking.delete()

        return Response({"success": "Booking cancelled and dates are now available again"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Booking.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"error": "Booking does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"error": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)


my urls.py for Booking app
    path('remove/<int:booking_id>/', cancel_the_booking , name="cancel_the_booking")


and my project urls.py is
    path("bookings/", include("Bookings.urls")),

to retrive the csrf
@api_view(["GET"])
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def get_csrf_token(request):
    csrf_token = get_token(request)
    return JsonResponse({'csrfToken': csrf_token})


path('api/get-csrf-token/', get_csrf_token, name='get_csrf_token'),


React Native code
  const getCsrfToken = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Api.get('/api/get-csrf-token/');
      return response.data.csrfToken;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching CSRF token', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const handleConfirmButton = (booking) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Cancel Booking',
      'Are you sure you want to cancel this booking?',
      [
        {
          text: 'No',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          onPress: () => handleBookingCancellation(booking),
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

const handleBookingCancellation = async (booking) => {
  try {
    const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken();
    if (!csrfToken) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to fetch CSRF token');
      return;
    }

    const response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/bookings/remove/?booking_id=${booking.booking_id}/`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${await SecureStore.getItemAsync('access')}`,
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken 
      },
    });

    Alert.alert("Booking Cancelled", `Booking ID: ${booking.booking_id}`);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error cancelling booking', error);
    Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error cancelling the booking');
  }
};


        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.confirmButton } onPress={() => handleConfirmButton(item)} >
            <Text style={styles.viewAllText}>Cancel Booking</Text>
            <AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="white" style={styles.icon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

I have tried multiple approaches to resolve the 403 Forbidden (CSRF token missing) error specifically for the /bookings/remove/ endpoint:

Fetching the CSRF Token:

Implemented a CSRF token fetch from the backend using a dedicated endpoint (/api/get-csrf-token/).
The token fetch works correctly and returns a valid CSRF token.

Sending the CSRF Token in Requests:

Modified the fetch request in React Native to include the CSRF token in the headers.
Expected the backend to accept the request and process the booking cancellation.

Adjusting Django Settings:

Ensured CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS and CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS include the frontend URLs.
Enabled CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS.

Changing HTTP Method and Headers:

Tried using both POST and DELETE methods.
Included necessary headers (Authorization, Content-Type, and X-CSRFToken).
Despite these efforts, the request to /bookings/remove/ consistently results in a 403 Forbidden (CSRF token missing) error. Other endpoints are functioning correctly without this issue, which is confusing.
I was expecting the request to succeed, cancel the booking, and return a confirmation response, but it fails at the CSRF validation stage.
I expected that after correctly fetching and including the CSRF token in the request headers, the backend would validate the token and allow the booking cancellation request to proceed without returning a 403 Forbidden error.
while everything working fine with postman.

First of all,
If you are want to use the
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
]

so you don't need SESSION settings anymore(remove them) and also use one of the JWT or Token for your authentication cycle. But about your problem, I think it raises from your middleware, You put it in wrong place. The CORS middleware should be replaced before COMMON middleware not in the top of all other middleware. Change its place(read CORS documentation) so your middleware should looks like this :
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Let me know if something get wrong again. If still your CSRF has problem add this line to your settings :
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8081/",
]

And about your React Native codes : You use the POST method to fetch user data from backend which is right but why this piece of code :
const getCsrfToken = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Api.get('/api/get-csrf-token/');
      return response.data.csrfToken;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching CSRF token', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

When you send POST request to the backend, all data that user needs, like token and response should come automatically, no need above code. For more information see this github repo : JWT Auth with DRF and React
I read your question again ... Do you want to delete a booking object? Am I right? so in this case : You will need to use DELETE header instead of POST header. your view should looks like this :
@api_view(["DELETE"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
# @csrf_exempt # uncomment it out, If you'v faced the CSRF error
def cancel_the_booking(request, booking_id):
    pass


It Does not solve the issue, still getting the same error even after adding CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in settings.
